# Load local file UIWebview before transition

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I searched alot for this but couldnt find a perfect answer.

My Ios app has its every page in UIWebview.

The only problem I am facing is when **transiting** from one page to another, the loading of UIWebview takes 1-2 seconds and the user sees a white background. Since all the html, css, image files are stored locally,  **how can I preload the UIWebview before transition?** So that the user gets native feel.

I am loading the URL this way :

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"start" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"main/html"]];
NSString *path = [url absoluteString];
NSURL *filePath = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",path,@"?logged_in=1"]];
[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:filePath]];
```

I am using a different viewcontroller for each page as I want the native push and modal transitions.

Comment: it always take some delay bro , if you need some thing show the activity control on loading time

Comment: sry bro , actvity indicator bro